# I am trying to save a file but getting an error

Tags: python, python-3.x, typeerror

While trying to save a file I get the following error:

Error:

TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not _io.TextIOWrapper

Code:

```
def save_file(self):

        if self.file is None:
            # Save as new file
            self.file = asksaveasfile(initialfile='Untitled.txt',
                                      defaultextension=".txt",
                                      filetypes=[("All Files", "*.*"),
                                                 ("Text Documents", "*.txt")])

            if self.file == "":
                self.file = None
            else:
                # try to save the file
                file = open(self.file.name, 'w') # Error: expected str, bytes or  os.PathLike object, not _io.TextIOWrapper
                file.write(self.this_text_area.get(1.0, END))
                file.close()

                # change the window title
                self.root.title(os.path.basename(self.file) + " - ")
```

I am trying to save the file but getting an error as shown above. I can open the file but cannot save the contents in it. Can anyone help me understand this please?

Comment: It's telling you that `self.file.name` is not a string.  Why don't you see what type it is, and then fix it to be what you want?  Try printing `type(self.file.name)`.  Look at `asksaveasfile`.  Apparently it isn't returning what you expect.

Comment: Yes, `asksaveasfile` is expecting a string value. I entered `file = open(".txt", 'w')`, still the same error.

Comment: this code seems a bit "messy". First: Why is the extension twice in the `asksaveeasfile` function (`unteitlted.txt` with extension `txt`)? Second: it is unclear what `asksaveasfile` does and how it looks like? I could imagine you wanted to create a `dict` maybe? `asksaveasfile = {"initialfile": "untitled", "defaultextension": "txt", "filetypes": ...}` and call it with `file = open(asksaveasfile["initialfile"] + asksaveasfile["defaultextension"], "w")` ?